# How to arrange HTML table in jinja2 according to the value of table content?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to arrange rows of table according to highest content value of column Points(PT)

This is my code:

```
<table class="standings-datatable table table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">TEAM</th>

            <th class="bg-dark text-lg-center">M</th>
            <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">W</th>
            <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">L</th>
            <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">T</th>
            <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">N/R</th>
            <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">PT</th>
            <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">NRR</th>
            <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">FOR</th>
            <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">AGAINST</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for key in tabledata %}
        <tr class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td><img class="team-logo" src="/static/{{ key["Sydney image"] }}">{{ key["Sydney Thunders name"]}}</td>
                <td>{{ key['Sydney THunder M'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ key['Sydney THunder W'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ key['Sydney THunder L'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ key['Sydney THunder T'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ key['Sydney THunder N/R'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ key['Sydney THunder PT'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ key['Sydney THunder NRR'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ key['Sydney THunder FOR'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ key['Sydney THunder AGAINST'] }}</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>

        <td><img class="team-logo" src="/static/{{ key["Brisbane image"] }}">{{ key["Brisbane name"]}}</td>
        <td>{{ key['Brisbane Heat M'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ key['Brisbane Heat W'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ key['Brisbane Heat L'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ key['Brisbane Heat T'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ key['Brisbane Heat N/R'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ key['Brisbane Heat PT'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ key['Brisbane Heat NRR'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ key['Brisbane Heat FOR'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ key['Brisbane Heat AGAINST'] }}</td>

        </tr>

        {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If two rows have same value of point (PT), then next column to be given preference  is (NRR), How can I achieve this?, If you have any other questions please ask me, thanks

fixed: I arranged the data in order before rendering into templates, I changed my code as to calculate highest point and NRR basis as suggested by one of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to sort the data into the order you require before rendering it in the template.  In your case, you probably want to reorganise the structure of your data by removing the link between team names and statistics in the key names, because that makes it impossible to easily sort the data.

Organise your data as a `list` of `dicts`, each `dict` has these keys:

'Name' (team name), 
'image', 
'M', 
'W', 
'L', 
'T', 
'N/R', 
'PT', 
'NRR', 
'FOR', 
'AGAINST'

Now you can sort your list of teams, using the `list` objects `sort` method; you need to provide a function to the sort method that tells it how to sort the data.  You can use a lambda function that returns a team's `PT` and `NRR` values; the sort function will use the first value (PT) first, then NRR if PTs are equal.  The `sort` method's `reverse` argument sorts the data in descending order, that is the teams with the most points will be first in the list.

```
>>> teams = [{'name': 'Sydney Thunder', 'PT': 5, 'NRR': 0.5}, {'name': 'Brisbane Heat', 'PT': 5, 'NRR': 0.75}, {'name': 'Someone Else', 'PT': 6, 'NRR': 0.2}] 
>>> teams.sort(key=lambda x: (x['PT'], x['NRR']), reverse=True)
>>> teams
[{'name': 'Someone Else', 'PT': 6, 'NRR': 0.2}, {'name': 'Brisbane Heat', 'PT': 5, 'NRR': 0.75}, {'name': 'Sydney Thunder', 'PT': 5, 'NRR': 0.5}]
```

Pass the sorted list to your template and loop over it:

```
{% for team in teams %}

<tr>

    <td><img class="team-logo" src="/static/{{ team["image"] }}">{{ team["name"]}}</td>
    <td>{{ team['M'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ team['W'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ team['L'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ team['T'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ team['N/R'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ team['PT'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ team['NRR'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ team['FOR'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ team['AGAINST'] }}</td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
```